# Have an javascript error: Unexpected token '.', using jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium, css-selectors

Моя идея ругается на третью строку данного кода

```
    public void getCoordinates(){
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("return $(.flash).position()", flashElement);
}
```

Выдаёт следующую ошибку

> org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Unexpected token '.'

я использую Jquery в Java проекте и не могу понять, где именно тут лишняя точка.

FlashElement у меня определён верно, тут я не сомневаюсь

```
 @FindBy(className = "flash")
    WebElement flashElement;
```

Comment: return $('.flash').position()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так попробуйте

```
 public void getCoordinates(){
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("return $(\".flash\").position()", flashElement);
}
```

либо

```
public void getCoordinates(){
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("return $('.flash').position()", flashElement);
}
```